# How to add units to integer values in XML?

Tags: android, xml

Currently, I'm working on an Android project where I define integers in the `values` directory within an `Resource XML file`. I'm trying to use these integers to set the text size and margin of one of my TextViews. When I try run my code, I keep getting a compiler error because I can't define the units (`dp`, `sp`). What is the correct syntax for this?

TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@integer/margin_bottom"
        android:textSize="@integer/text_size"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:id="@+id/txtNew"/>
```

Resources File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="margin_bottom">5</integer>
    <integer name="text_size">50</integer>
</resources>
```

Comment: You want to define `<dimen>` resources instead; e.g., `<dimen name="margin_bottom">5dp</dimen>`, and then `android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"` in the layout.

Comment: @MikeM. is it possible to access this value in a java activity class?

Comment: Which value, exactly? The resource ID would be `R.dimen.margin_bottom` in your code. The resulting measure can be obtained by passing that to a `Resources#getDimension*()` method. The docs might be helpful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension.